# C# IPv6 Server error

Tags: c#, ipv6

I'm trying to create a small HTTP server in C# but I'm having some trouble with IPv6 clients. I have IPv6 support on my machine but when I try to create a listening socket it fails.

```
Log("Creating server socket on port {0}", LogType.Info, _port);
            _serversocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _serversocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port));
            _serversocket.Listen(10);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The code throws this exception:
The system detected an invalid pointer address in attempting to use a pointer argument in a call

EDIT:

Stack Trace:

> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress
>   socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint
>   localEP)    at
>   TroutServer.Trout.Start(Int32 port) in
>   C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\TroutServer\trout\trout.cs:line
>   62

Type is SocketException

Comment: What is the exception's type and stack trace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, _port)
```